# MVC 4 & Knockout Display in a Splash Screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, knockout.js

I have a some checkboxes on the page next  to reports that can be run. When the user hits the button on the page if a checkbox is checked the report will be run and a spalsh screen will pop up that says "Please wait reports are running".  I have that working in code below! BUT what I want to do is display the name of the report  in the splash screen so if report 1 was checked the slash screen says "Please wait REPORT 1 is running" or if report 2 is checked the splash screen says "Please wait REPORT 2 is running".

Here is my view. The div "divLoading"... is the splash screen that pops up.

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.ReportModel
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {
<div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px;
top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666666; z-index: 30001;
opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=70);display:none">
<p style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
    Running reports, please wait...<img src="../../Images/ajax-loading.gif">
</p>
</div>
<section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
        </hgroup>

        <div id="inputContainer">

        </div>

        <div id="reportContainer">
            Run report
            <span data-bind="text: Date"></span>


            <table>
                <tr style="font-weight:bold">

                    <td>
                        Report Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Number Of Rows
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       Has Data
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Result Message
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Check
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tbody data-bind="foreach: Report">
                    <tr>
                        <td> <span data-bind="text: ReportName"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: NumberOfRows"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: HasData"></span></td>
                        <td><span data-bind="text: ResultMessage"></span></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkBox"></td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>

        </table>            
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
}
 <button onclick="JavascriptFunction();">HTTPPost Button</button>
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

//SET INITIAL VALUES ON PAGE WITH KNOCKOUT
    @*var initialModel = new KOViewModel(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));*@
    var initialModel =   @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
    @*var initialModel2 = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Model.ToString()))*@
//SET THE KNOCKOUT OBSERVABLES
var viewmodel =
   {
       Date: ko.observable(initialModel.Date),
       Report: ko.observableArray(initialModel.ReportList)
   };
        //FUNCTION TO SHOW A LOADING SCREEN
        function JavascriptFunction() {
            var url = '@Url.Action("PostMethod", "Home")';
            $("#divLoading").show();

            var postModel = {
                ReportDate: viewmodel.Date(),
                ReportList: viewmodel.Report()
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: ko.toJSON( postModel),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (res) {
                    $("#divLoading").fadeOut(100);
                    viewmodel.Date(res.ReportDate);
                    viewmodel.Report(res.ReportList);
                }
            });
        }

//APPLY KNOCKOUT BINDINGS
$(document).ready(function() {
   ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);

});
</script>
    }
```

Here is my controller. Please see the comments in the "Post Method":

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new ReportModel();
        model.ReportDate = "1/31/2014";
        model.ReportList = new List<Models.Common.Rep>();
        //add a report
        model.ReportList.Add(
              new Models.Common.Rep()
            {
                ReportName = "Report 1",
                NumberOfRows = 50,
                HasData = "Yes",
                checkBox = false,
                ResultMessage = "Message"
            });
        model.ReportList.Add(

            //add another report
     new Models.Common.Rep()
     {
         ReportName = "Report 2",
         NumberOfRows = 50,
         HasData = "Yes 2",
         checkBox = false,
         ResultMessage = "Message 2"
     });

        return View(model);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostMethod(ReportModel model)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        model.ReportDate = "1/31/2014";
        foreach (var row in model.ReportList)
        {
            if(row.checkBox == true)
            {
                 //if the report is checked this simulates the running of the report
                 //I want to show the reportname on the div when the report it running
                 ///should i be setting something to ???  =  row.ReportName
                 row.NumberOfRows = 3000;
            }

        }

        return Json(model); 
    }
```

And is the ReportModel and Rep Class:

```
    public class ReportModel
    {
        public string ReportDate { get; set; }
        public List<Common.Rep> ReportList { get; set; }
    }

public class Rep
{
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfRows { get; set; }
    public string HasData { get; set; }
    public bool checkBox { get; set; }
    public string ResultMessage { get; set; }
}
```

How can I make the  "divLoading" display the row.ReportName that is running?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that you are submitting an object stating to run 10 reports, and each of those is running on the server, but there is no mechanism for sending the status updates for each report back to the client.

The simplest solution for this would be to do the loop of selected reports on the client and issue the server request for one report at a time - now you could set a "currentReport" observable property and bind to that.

Alternatively, you would need to set up some other way of sending those status updates back to the client wither via WebSocket or Server Sent Events perhaps.  The first approach would be far simpler, but lose any potential concurrency on the server.

Hope that helps!